# How to change height and width of page layout in google sites

Tags: google-sites

When I create a site there's a lot of white space around a section. That's the only section and I'd like to have a tiny margin.

Is it possible to change the margin/padding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It helps to distinguish between *classic* and *new* Google Sites when asking questions, as the answer is not always the same for each.

Assuming you mean new Google Sites then as far as your question is concerned, the answer is no.

New Google Sites is pretty good at automatically configuring the output for different sizes, and orientation, of screens to support monitors, tablets, and phones. The trade off for that is that you loose some control over how the content is displayed; including margins and padding.

You can embed your own HTML, and have far more control of what happens with that section of display. But not outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Page frames can be changed with 3 width options since April 2023:

- Normal (Default): Designed for more spread out sites with less content
- Full: Designed for dense, content-heavy sites
- Wide: Designed for sites that fall between normal and full

This can be done via using a custom theme and adjustments in ->Spacing.
Details please have a look at: https://support.google.com/sites/thread/211027951/google-sites-new-feature-site-width-and-page-frames?hl=en